# Creating multiple directories at once using a shell script with mkdir and variables

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I want to create a directory tree as follow using `mkdir` in a shell script.

```
Tutorial
│
├── abc
│   |
│   └── def
│       
└── pqr
    ├── stu
    │   
    └── vwx
```

When I run the following command in terminal,

```
mkdir -p /home/LinuxServer/GIT/bbb/Tutorial/{abc/def,pqr/{stu,vwx}}
```

then it is working.

But when I execute following shell script it does not create the directory tree properly

```
DIRECTORY_PATH="/home/LinuxServer/GIT/bbb/"
CREATE_DIRECTORY_STRUCTURE="Tutorial/{abc/def,pqr/{stu,vwx}}"
TUTORIAL_PATH="$DIRECTORY_PATH$CREATE_DIRECTORY_STRUCTURE"

mkdir -p  $TUTORIAL_PATH
```

Can you please help me understand this problem?

Comment: (a) looks like school homework; if so do it.   (b) not related to ubuntu

Comment: You should provide a bit more details here. When running your shell script, do you get an error message? Does it create (at least some) directories?

Comment: @guiverc are home works forbidden here? He showed he tried and should be assisted!

Comment: true @George (he had tried) - my mistake. sorry Bhargav

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Brace expansion takes place well before variable expansion, and does not happen during variable assignment:

```
$ foo={a,b,c}
$ echo $foo
{a,b,c}
```

Keep the common parts in the variable and the rest in the command itself:

```
DIRECTORY_PATH="/home/LinuxServer/GIT/bbb/"
TUTORIAL_PATH="${DIRECTORY_PATH}Tutorial"

mkdir -p  "$TUTORIAL_PATH"/{abc/def,pqr/{stu,vwx}}
```

The other option is to use arrays, where brace expansion does happen during assignment:

```
TUTORIAL_PATHS=( "${DIRECTORY_PATH}Tutorial"/{abc/def,pqr/{stu,vwx}} )
mkdir -p "${TUTORIAL_PATH[@]}"
```

Comment: Just to reinforce this answer: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html#Shell-Expansions. "The order of expansions is: brace expansion; tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, arithmetic expansion, and command substitution (done in a left-to-right fashion); word splitting; and filename expansion." Here the braces are never expanded because it's too late after variable expansion has already happened.